# jQuery nav collapse scroll change speed

Tags: javascript, html

The following is a standard jQuery scroll function for nav-bar collapsing that I found on sof. For some reason, when I try to change the default speed of the header-wrap, it isn't changing. I can't figure out why. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header-wrap').hide();
})

var previousScroll = 0, headerOrgOffset = $('#header').height();
$('#header-wrap').height($('#header').height());

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
        if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
            $('#header-wrap').slideDown( "slow", function() {
            // Animation complete.
            });
        } else {
            $('#header-wrap').slideUp();
        }
    } 
    previousScroll = currentScroll;
});
```

```
<!-- Navigation Scroll Bar-->
<div id="header-wrap">
<div id="header" class="clear">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="services.html">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-1-col.html">1 Column Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-2-col.html">2 Column Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-3-col.html">3 Column Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-4-col.html">4 Column Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-item.html">Single Portfolio Item</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Blog <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="blog-home-1.html">Blog Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="blog-home-2.html">Blog Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="blog-post.html">Blog Post</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Other Pages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="full-width.html">Full Width Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="sidebar.html">Sidebar Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="404.html">404</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pricing.html">Pricing Table</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give us the HTML code as well?

Comment: posted. HTML is a default standard bootstrap template for nav. NAV is a child wrapped inside header-wrap.